# Ball movement simulation

Tags: sphere, scenekit

I'm doing a little demo with scene kit and i want to simulate the rotation of a ball on a table. How can i achieve this?
This is the scene that i prepared:

[image]

Comment: You are going to need to rotate the ball using a 4x4 matrix in order to avoid [gimbal lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock)

Comment: Or you could also use Quaternions. Look up 3D rotations, you'll find both Quaternion and Matrix implementations.